# python sqlalchemy parallel operation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

HI，i got a multi-threading program which all threads will operate on oracle
DB. So, can sqlalchemy support parallel operation on oracle?

tks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCI (oracle client interface) has a parameter OCI_THREADED which has the effect of connections being mutexed, such that concurrent access via multiple threads is safe.  This is likely the setting the document you saw was referring to.

`cx_oracle`, which is essentially a Python->OCI bridge, provides access to this setting in its connection function using the keyword argument "threaded", described at http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect .   The docs state that it is False by default due to its resulting in a "10-15% performance penalty", though no source is given for this information (and performance stats should always be viewed suspiciously as a rule).

As far as SQLAlchemy, the `cx_oracle` dialect provided with SQLAlchemy sets this value to True by default, with the option to set it back to False when setting up the engine via create_engine() - so at that level there's no issue.

But beyond that, SQLAlchemy's recommended usage patterns (i.e. one Session per thread, keeping connections local to a pool where they are checked out by a function as needed) prevent concurrent access to a connection in any case.   So you can likely turn off the "threaded" setting on create_engine() and enjoy the possibly-tangible performance increases provided regular usage patterns are followed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as each concurrent thread has it's own session you should be fine. Trying to use one shared session is where you'll get into trouble.

Comment: tks，since oracle official document said that you should enable something(don`t know what "something" is yet...) for oracle to use parallel ability..
What should i do in sqlalchemy?